# Is there a special limit in the range of the hash function?

Tags: hash, rsa, homomorphic-encryption, collision-resistance, elgamal-encryption

Is there a special limit in the range of the hash function?

More specifically, is it possible that there is a cryptographic hash function that outputs c-membered subsets of the n-membered set?
In other words, can the set of the binary representation of "all" c-membered subsets of the n-membered set, be the range of a hash function?

(One idea would be that we assume a hash function which outputs a number in rang {1,2,3, ...,  n!/(n-c)!}.
In this manner, we can assign each number in that rang to a specific c-membered subset of the n-membered set. Does it make sense?)

Comment: X-OF hashes are designed for long output, this is what you may needed. See SHAKE series of SHA3

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks a lot. So can we conclude that there is a collision resistant hash function with the below domain and rang:   H: G $rightarrow$ {1,2,3, ..., n!/(n-c)!}.                                                                                                  in other word,  H: G $rightarrow$ Z_{ n!/(n-c)!}

Comment: Well, how large is the domain? That is important...

Comment: @kelalaka the group G is (Z/NZ)×, where N = pq for a pair of distinct prime numbers p and q.